# Where can I find OpenVPN Connect for Windows?

Tags: download, openvpn, software-update

A few months ago, I have installed a program called "OpenVPN Connect" (from OpenVPN Technologies) and I wanted to check if there were any recent updates, but I couldn't find any trace of that program anywhere, with the exception of [a single link which I refuse to trust](https://ironsocket.com/setup/windows-7/openvpn). It is just a simple systray icon with popup a menu, very easy to use, unlike OpenVPN Client which is much more complex.

I do not remember how I originally got this program, but I am looking into downloading it again. Where can I find it?

*Update* I found another link on [ipfw.edu](http://www.ipfw.edu/training/kb/network-internet/openvpn-connect-for-windows.html) which requires authentication for the download. This link has screenshots which show how OpenVPN Connect is used.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenVPN connect client you are referring to is part of the OpenVPN Access Server. Since the Client seems to be bundled into the Access Server, client updates are probably distributed together with Access Server updates (I may be wrong here, it has been a while since I've used that product).

You can download the connect client from your own OpenVPN server.

In a nutshell, go to https://<VPN IP Address> , enter your username and password and select "Login" in the dropdown, that should bring you to the client downloads.

https://openvpn.net/images/pdf/OpenVPN_Access_Server_Sysadmin_Guide_Rev.pdf 
Page 44 onward has more detailed information about the OpenVPN connect client and how/where you can access and download it.